# Yield not stopping the flow in ember concurrency task

Tags: javascript, ember.js, yield, ember-concurrency

```
if (isEmpty(contact) || isEmpty(get(contact, 'emails'))) {
  contact = yield store.findRecord('contact', contactId);
}

if (isEmpty(contact) || isEmpty(get(contact, 'emails'))) {
  flashMessages.danger(i18n.t('email.cpq_document_email_missing'));
  return false;
}
```

The second block runs when the promise is running and Im getting an error. Shouldn't it stop the flow until the promise is resolved.

The promise runs fine and it works the next time

Comment: Yes, assuming you're using ember-data `findRecord` should return a promise and wait. Please include all of the code in your component as well as the error you're seeing because the issue doesn't seem to be in this block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `ember-data`, you may be encountering a case where `findRecord` returns a cached record. This depends on if you've already loaded the record (perhaps from a previous `findRecord`, `findAll` or `query` on another route, and how the `ember-data` adapter is configured: [`shouldBackgroundReloadRecord`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.22/classes/Adapter/methods/shouldBackgroundReloadRecord?anchor=shouldBackgroundReloadRecord) and [`shouldBackgroundReloadAll`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.22/classes/Adapter/methods/shouldBackgroundReloadRecord?anchor=shouldBackgroundReloadAll) are methods on the adapter that default to returning `true`. When those methods return `true`, the cached record is immediately returned, but the record(s) are fetched again in the "background".

Comment: This makes sense, I already have the contact object, but it doesn't have emails properties so I'm fetching it again. Is there a way I can stop it from using the cached data?

Comment: Adding { reload: true } fixed it, thanks for the clarification